# TableView doesn't fetch items from array

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview

I'm having a problem about my tableView. I added a bunch of items into an array and asked the tableView to populate itself with those items from the array, it worked fine, but when I changed the items' indexes (orders) in array, the tableView didn't display the items correctly. I knew my array and its items' orders worked as I expected because NSLogs told me so. Can anybody help me on this? Thanks in advance!

This is the method that I used to add new item:

```
- (IBAction)AddNewItem:(id)sender{
    BNRItem *newItem = [[VKItemStore sharedStore] createItem];
    NSInteger lastRow = [[VKItemStore sharedStore].itemsArray indexOfObject:newItem];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop]; 
}
```

and this is how I changed the order of items in the array:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableArray *items = [VKItemStore sharedStore].itemsArray;

    if (items.count == 2) {
        items[0] = items[1];
        items[1] = [VKItemStore sharedStore].item;
     }

    NSLog(@"AFTER ARRAY: %@", items);
    BNRItem *item = items[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item description];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I think inside your AddNewItem: method you are adding the item in itemsArray and in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method accessing the item from privateItems array.

Comment: As I understand, your code always add new row to end of table.What do you want? if your table doesn't update you can try this code.        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop]; 
        [self.tableView endUpdates];

Comment: It's actually a typo I made, privateItems and itemsArray are exactly the same, I updated the code for you now, please have a look. Thanks! @iDeveloper

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work @muhammedkasva

Answer (score 0):

Change you if block with this code may be this will help you

```
if (items.count == 2) {
        BNRItem *item  = items[0];
        items[0] = items[1];
        items[1] = item;
     }
```

Because your [VKItemStore sharedStore].item will have your current item only that is last object of your array items[1]. and you are storing it in items[1] same object. so try the above code may be it will help you.

Comment: I should have named them differently though to avoid confusion. Actually, the [VKItemStore sharedStore].item is a unique item that I predefined for my array, so that every time the app launches, that unique item always appear on the tableView. At this stage, addNewItem: hasn't been called. When I call it, it adds a new item to the existing array and below that [VKItemStore sharedStore].item and I tried to reverse their indexes. NSLogs showed me that the array was updated, but tableView wasn't fetching any updates from the new array! Please help! Thanks ! @iDeveloper

Comment: try to change the line [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop]; with [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: According to your code I have observed you must be getting the same item(item[0]) in your both row of table after adding one, because you only reloading the table for indexPath.row=1 not for 0 so 0 will remain same and row 1 will populated with item[0]. I hope I am right if not tell me the result of your table.

Comment: Your code only works when there are two items in array, however i've found solution for this problem now, just change this line from: NSInteger lastRow = [[VKItemStore sharedStore].itemsArray indexOfObject:newItem]; to NSInteger lastRow = [[VKItemStore sharedStore].itemsArray indexOfObject:newItem] - 1; @iDeveloper. Anyway, thank you so much for your time! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Change this line of code:

```
NSInteger lastRow = [[VKItemStore sharedStore].itemsArray indexOfObject:newItem];
```

so that it becomes:

```
NSInteger lastRow = [[VKItemStore sharedStore].itemsArray indexOfObject:newItem] - 1;
```